# Android spinner didn't trigger onItemSelected

Tags: android, spinner

In my application, I use spinner, it shows with `spinner.performClick()`. After a lot of tries I noticed that my code does not trigger `onItemSelected method`, Then I tried to add `@Override` annotation but it returns as error and says delete that annotation. here is that code:

```
Spinner colorSpinner = new Spinner(this);
ColorFriendsSpinnerAdapter adapter = new ColorFriendsSpinnerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), liste, R.layout.color_dropdown, new String[] { "Icon" }, new int[] { R.id.colorDropdown });
//adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
colorSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
colorSpinner.performClick();

colorSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) { 
               editColorXml(position);
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Thanks for any help, and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1):

A sample of ItemSelectedListner , no need of override annotation .

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

set listener before `colorSpinner.performClick()` . in this code spinner will be clicked at the moment where no listener is set .

Comment: still doesn't trigger onItemSelected method. I tried to set onClickListener inside adapter but it doesn't work either.

Comment: I have this problem when I create spinner at code and couldn't solve so I didn't use it. You can solve this problem with creating spinner at your layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code..

```
final List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("Item 1");
list.add("Item 2");
list.add("Item 3");
list.add("Item 4");
list.add("Item 5");

final Spinner sp1= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

ArrayAdapter<String> adp1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
adp1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
sp1.setAdapter(adp1);

sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), list.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  @Override
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
  }
});
```